# Sort array of objects using three levels of custom sort criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of objects using three levels of custom sorting criteria.

```
firstLevelSortOrder = ['10K','20K','30K','40K','50K']
secondLevelSortOrder = ['ACTIVE','CONSUMED','EXPIRED']
thirdLevelSortOrder = 
1) Oldest bountyIssueDate in case of multiple ACTIVE objects
2) Latest bountyIssueDate in case of multiple CONSUMED objects
3) Latest bountyIssueDate in case multiple EXPIRED objects
```

**Array to sort** :

```
let bountyList = [
  {
    "bountyCode": "10K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "13 Jan 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "20K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "13 Feb 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "30K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "13 Mar 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "EXPIRED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "40K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "13 Apr 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "50K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "13 May 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "10K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "29 May 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "ACTIVE"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "10K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "06 Jun 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "ACTIVE"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "30K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "15 Mar 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
    {
    "bountyCode": "40K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "23 Apr 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  }
]
```

**Result array:**

```
[
  {
    "bountyCode": "10K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "29 May 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "ACTIVE"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "10K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "06 Jun 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "ACTIVE"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "10K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "13 Jan 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "20K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "13 Feb 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "30K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "15 Mar 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "30K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "13 Mar 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "EXPIRED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "40K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "23 Apr 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "40K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "03 Apr 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "50K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "13 May 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  }
]
```

I've got the first level of sort working which is here in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ebragf1/). 
Hitting a dead end trying to integrate the second and third level sort order. Also tried separating out the duplicates into a separate array, sorting them and then merge them into a master array, its getting very messy.

Comment: The second level you can simply integrate the same as the first, right?

Comment: Hi, i was thinking on this and @YannickK is rigth and wrong. cause integrating the same system for second layer is gonna bump the first ordering. I believe what u need to do, first group them with `bountyCode`, second apply 2. and 3. sorting issues, and then concat them at last

Comment: @YannickK implementing the same thing for the second order is causing the first one to break

Comment: Oh while reading the third one, I'm guessing you need to group those too as `ACTIVE`, `CONSUMED`  and `EXPIRED` and sort seperatly and then concat them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement this based on checking each sort criteria in order. If the first level sort criteria gives a result, return that. Otherwise, check the second level. If that gives a result, return that. Otherwise, return the result of the third level criteria:

```js
var bountyList = [{
    "bountyCode": "10K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "13 Jan 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "20K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "13 Feb 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "30K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "13 Mar 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "EXPIRED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "40K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "13 Apr 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "50K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "13 May 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "10K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "29 May 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "ACTIVE"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "10K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "06 Jun 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "ACTIVE"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "30K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "15 Mar 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "40K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "23 Apr 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  }
]

var firstLevelSortOrder = ['10K', '20K', '30K', '40K', '50K']
var secondLevelSortOrder = ['ACTIVE', 'CONSUMED', 'EXPIRED']

console.log(bountyList.sort(
  function(a, b) {
    var first = firstLevelSortOrder.indexOf(a.bountyCode) - firstLevelSortOrder.indexOf(b.bountyCode);
    if (first != 0) {
      return first;
    }
    // first order equal, test second order
    var second = secondLevelSortOrder.indexOf(a.bountyStatus) - secondLevelSortOrder.indexOf(b.bountyStatus);
    if (second != 0) {
      return second;
    }
    // second order also equal, test dates dependent on bountyStatus
    if (a.bountyStatus == 'ACTIVE') {
      // want earliest date sorted first
      return Date.parse(a.bountyIssueDate) - Date.parse(b.bountyIssueDate);
    } 
    else {
      // want latest date sorted first for CONSUMED or EXPIRED
      return Date.parse(b.bountyIssueDate) - Date.parse(a.bountyIssueDate);
    }
  }
))
```

Note that for convenience to demonstrate the code I've used [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to parse the dates in your objects. In general this is not recommended due to browser inconsistencies (see the manual) and you should manually parse the dates into a timestamp for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Sort compare function, check whether code same or not. 
if same code, then check for status
if same status, then check for date.

```js
let bountyList = [
  {
    bountyCode: "10K",
    bountyIssueDate: "13 Jan 2020",
    bountyStatus: "CONSUMED",
  },
  {
    bountyCode: "20K",
    bountyIssueDate: "13 Feb 2020",
    bountyStatus: "CONSUMED",
  },
  {
    bountyCode: "30K",
    bountyIssueDate: "13 Mar 2020",
    bountyStatus: "EXPIRED",
  },
  {
    bountyCode: "40K",
    bountyIssueDate: "13 Apr 2020",
    bountyStatus: "CONSUMED",
  },
  {
    bountyCode: "50K",
    bountyIssueDate: "13 May 2020",
    bountyStatus: "CONSUMED",
  },
  {
    bountyCode: "10K",
    bountyIssueDate: "29 May 2020",
    bountyStatus: "ACTIVE",
  },
  {
    bountyCode: "10K",
    bountyIssueDate: "06 Jun 2020",
    bountyStatus: "ACTIVE",
  },
  {
    bountyCode: "30K",
    bountyIssueDate: "15 Mar 2020",
    bountyStatus: "CONSUMED",
  },
  {
    bountyCode: "40K",
    bountyIssueDate: "23 Apr 2020",
    bountyStatus: "CONSUMED",
  },
];

const compare = (a, b) => {
  const av = parseInt(a.bountyCode);
  const bv = parseInt(b.bountyCode);
  const status = ["ACTIVE", "CONSUMED", "EXPIRED"];
  if (av === bv) {
    const as = status.indexOf(a.bountyStatus);
    const bs = status.indexOf(b.bountyStatus);
    if (as !== bs) {
      return as - bs;
    } else if (as === 0) {
      return a.bountyIssueDate > b.bountyIssueDate;
    } else {
      return a.bountyIssueDate < b.bountyIssueDate;
    }
  } else {
    return av - bv;
  }
};

bountyList.sort(compare);

console.log(bountyList);
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are great but I wanted some easy solution not requiring conditional statement. I just sort by level 1 and level 2 arrays without considering the date.

```
var bountyList = [{
    "bountyCode": "10K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "13 Jan 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "20K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "13 Feb 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "30K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "13 Mar 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "EXPIRED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "40K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "13 Apr 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "50K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "13 May 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "10K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "29 May 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "ACTIVE"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "10K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "06 Jun 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "ACTIVE"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "30K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "15 Mar 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  },
  {
    "bountyCode": "40K",
    "bountyIssueDate": "23 Apr 2020",
    "bountyStatus": "CONSUMED"
  }
]

var firstLevelSortOrder = ['10K', '20K', '30K', '40K', '50K']
var secondLevelSortOrder = ['ACTIVE', 'CONSUMED', 'EXPIRED']
const res = bountyList.sort( function(a, b) {
    let lv1 = firstLevelSortOrder.indexOf(a.bountyCode) - firstLevelSortOrder.indexOf(b.bountyCode)
    let lv2 = firstLevelSortOrder.indexOf(a.bountyStatus) - firstLevelSortOrder.indexOf(b.bountyStatus);
    return lv2 - lv1;
}).reverse();
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer mate, your solution definitely looks nifty for the first 2 levels of sort.